# iOS Text & Images Blurred when using webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch

Tags: html, ios, css, ios5, mobile-safari

`webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`

This works perfectly in terms of scrolling, but it blurs the text and images noticeably in the `<DIV>` with `overflow: scroll` applied.  I have tried this on 3 different iPads with iOS5.

The easing/bounce algorithm native from Apple are much better than any JS equivalent, so I would like to start using this new feature! It is even more noticeable with the font I am required to use.

Here is a demo you can try from an iPad w/ iOS5:

http://sseeger.drivehq.com/test.htm [Stark, NO webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;]

http://sseeger.drivehq.com/test2.htm [Blurry, webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you were seeing is due to the default zooming of the ipad. Paul's response was on the right track but also unnecessarily disables user zooming. You just need to correctly set the initial scale and width of your screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

For my test case, try opening these two pages on an ipad:
http://www.jasonbuckboyer.com/playground/ios/overflow_scrolling/blurred.html  (Blurred)
http://www.jasonbuckboyer.com/playground/ios/overflow_scrolling/not_blurred.html (Not Blurred)

Answer (score 1):

`-webkit-perspective: 0;`

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be blurring in the iOS simulator. I can see why it would be blurry though with `webkit-overflow-scrolling` being used, as it needs to render the content differently when there is momentum involved (at least that's what I think).

As for a solution, you will have to wait for Apple to address the issue (if it even is affecting a wide audience).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following meta tag to your header section of your page.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = "no"/>
```